# Synchronizing speech and text

Tags: speech-recognition

I have a text and a narration of the exact same text. What is the best way to synchronize them together? By synchronizing I mean, finding out for example the location of each word in the audio. For example if the sentence is "I took a cab" I want for markers on the accompanying audio which indicate start of each word.

Obviously any speech-to-text algorithm can be applied here, but given the fact that we've already know the text, I wonder if there's an algorithm for this simplified problem which works either much faster, or gives much better performance. Or if there is a general algorithm that can be tuned for this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Papers on algorithms:

- [A RECURSIVE ALGORITHM FOR THE FORCED ALIGNMENT OF VERY LONG AUDIO SEGMENTS](http://www.isca-speech.org/archive/archive_papers/icslp_1998/i98_0068.pdf)
  Pedro J. Moreno, Chris Joerg, Jean-Manuel Van Thong and Oren Glickman
- [Automatic Alignment and Error Correction
  of Human Generated Transcripts for Long Speech Recordings](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/sls//publications/2006/IS061258.pdf)
  Timothy J. Hazen
- [SailAlign: Robust long speech-text alignment](http://sail.usc.edu/aigaion2/index.php/attachments/single/428)
  Authors Katsamanis, Athanasios
  Black, Matthew
  Georgiou, Panayiotis
  Goldstein, Louis
  Narayanan, Shrikanth S.

Implementations:

- [Sphinx4 long audio aligner](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2014/07/long-audio-aligner-landed-in-trunk/)
- [Sail align](https://github.com/nassosoassos/sail_align)
- [Gentle forced aligner](https://lowerquality.com/gentle/)